# Referenced classpath entry for JAR in local maven repository missing when importing nutch

Tags: eclipse, maven, nutch

I am trying to import nutch 1.4 into Eclipse. I cloned git repository and then build it using Maven. Then, I imported it in Eclipse as Maven project, but I'm getting the following error:

> The archive: /home/devang/.m2/repository/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behaviour when I had a project already imported in Eclipse, but then deleted the local Maven repository.

To solve this, make m2eclipse re-download the project's dependencies:

1. Right-click on the project and select *Maven > Update Project...*
2. Select *Force Update of Snapshots/Releases* and hit *OK*